# Autogenerate documentation for Python project using setuptools

Tags: python, python-sphinx, api-doc

I have created a demo project which uses setuptools and has the following structure:

```
project/
 |- pizza/
 |   |- __init__.py
 |   `- margherita.py
 |
 |- README.rst
 |- setup.cfg
 `- setup.py
```

I'm trying to autogenerate documentation for this project using Sphinx. So far I've tried:

```
# Generate a sphinx template
sphinx-quickstart
# Use default settings, except for project name, etc.
sphinx-apidoc -o source .
./setup.py build_sphinx
```

I feel there has to be an easier way to autogenerate this documentation using the `README`, `setup.py` and docstrings.

Ultimately I'd like to autogenerate apidocs for another project where I use the Python C-api as well. I couldn't find anything for this.

My main question is: Is there an easier way to autogenerate this documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sphinx-apidoc -F -o source .
```

Will generate a project with sphinx-quickstart and recursively look for python modules

You're about as efficient as you can be at the moment.

**=== Just wishful thinking below here ===**

Wouldn't it be lovely if you could call something like

```
./setup.py build_sphinx -C
```

and it would create you index.RST, read any RST files you had knocking about, parse all the docstrings and spit out some html.

Comment: Also the following flags will include some metadata: `-H $(./setup.py --name) -A $(./setup.py --author) -V $(./setup.py --version)`. Unfortunately this does not work for C extensions.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is quite an easy answer. I don't spot any effort to create a neat solution of some kind. The example you state (`/.setup.py build_sphinx -C`) looks right. This should be possible one way or another. Simply stating the use of `sphinx-apidoc` is not worth my bounty.

Comment: Agreed, good luck finding a more elegant solution. I'd like to know if you do

Answer (score 7):

To extend `setup.py` so it contains an extra command for Sphinx, you could create a custom command. I've cooked up a small example that runs Sphinx apidoc and then builds the doc sources. The project name, author, version and location of the sources defined in the `setup.py` are used (assuming they are defined).

```
class Sphinx(Command):
    user_options = []
    description = 'sphinx'

    def initialize_options(self):
        pass

    def finalize_options(self):
        pass

    def run(self):
        # metadata contains information supplied in setup()
        metadata = self.distribution.metadata
        # package_dir may be None, in that case use the current directory.
        src_dir = (self.distribution.package_dir or {'': ''})['']
        src_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),  src_dir)
        # Run sphinx by calling the main method, '--full' also adds a conf.py
        sphinx.apidoc.main(
            ['', '--full', '-H', metadata.name, '-A', metadata.author,
             '-V', metadata.version, '-R', metadata.version,
             '-o', os.path.join('doc', 'source'), src_dir])
        # build the doc sources
        sphinx.main(['', os.path.join('doc', 'source'),
                     os.path.join('doc', 'build')])
```

Then the command needs to be registered to the entry point group `distutils.commands`. Here the command is called `sphinx`.

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    # ...
    setup_requires = ['sphinx'],
    entry_points = {
        'distutils.commands': [
            'sphinx = example_module:Sphinx'
        ]
    }
)
```

I don't know how C sources are handled, but this'll get you started.

Comment: This was incredibly helpful. Thank you